# Matlab 'image processing'

Tags: matlab, rgb, pixel, mask, hsv

If I Get a Pixel Location from black and white image as `[row, column] = find(bw2 == 1)`; then I want to move this location to RGB image then how to remove this location or put mask instead of this location in RGB image. How to do this?

Comment: What do you want to replace it with?

Comment: I want after put this pixel location on rgb image to filling this area with neighbor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried something like this

```
[row, column] = find(bw2 == 1);

rgb_image(row,column) = 1; %assign value for the indices you found in your bw image; use 1 or whatever you want

bw2(row,column) = NaN; %or any other value, so next mask you won't select these indices
```

Comment: I hope it helped! If it solved your problem, could you mark the check mark next to my answer plz!